# AOP programming in .Net?

Tags: .net, aop, interception

I'm wondering what's good out there for AOP / crosscutting in .Net, along the lines of AspectJ.  I see Microsoft has a [Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572%28PandP.50%29.aspx); any other good stuff out there I should take a look at?

Comment: Have a look at this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#cite_note-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) is probably the most popular option, although I believe [Sprint.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) is fairly widespread, as well.

Comment: Here's a link to my notes on an AOP/PostSharp presentation by Michael Hall, if anyone's interested: http://www.truewill.net/iacodecamp2009/hall.htm

Answer (score 2):

I use [Microsoft Unity](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/AOPUnityInterfaceInterceptorExampleUnityDependencyInjectionTutorials.aspx) but there is also [StructureMap](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/01/27/interception-techniques-in-structuremap-2-5.aspx), [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html), [Castle Windsor](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/12/CastleWindsorContainerGenericsSupport.aspx) and, the most popular, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).

Comment: PostSharp is certainly AOP, but I'd call Unity and StructureMap IoC Container frameworks. Windsor and Spring do IoC and more, I think.

Comment: Both Unity an StructureMap have capabilities for AOP (see the links I provided for some examples). Depending on the problem trying to be solved, they are viable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not forget [LinFU](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/). Scott Hanselman did a great [interview about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast213AspectOrientedProgrammingAOPAndLinFuWithPhilipLaureano.aspx), including a lot of basics of AOP.

Answer (score 1):

I know of [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) which seems to be doing a lot of AOP-things really well using attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Spring.Net has an AOP framework which can be used with or without Spring's IoC framework. If you are also looking for an IoC framework, Spring.Net makes a compelling case and is free and open source.

Another plus for Spring.Net IMO is that the documentation and forum support really is excellent. One negative comment about Spring.Net that I have seen several times is that the XML configuration is wordy and difficult to read, which is true. It is however at least consistent so that once you have learned how it works for one block, you can apply it easily to other blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi Prism has compiler support for AOP

http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Cirrus

Answer (score 0):

[Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660891%28PandP.20%29.aspx) extension for [Microsoft Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/unity) gives you some AOP. In addition, see [Policy Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660915%28PandP.20%29.aspx) as one of the out-of-the-box interception behaviours.

Good examples and tutorials are included in this set of [Hands-on Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec&displaylang=en).