# A cleaner way to automatically call one method after another?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to design a method in such a fashion, that it knows it must automatically call a next method in succession upon exiting?

In the following example, I must call `Refresh()` to cause my form to repaint after this event takes place.  The problem is that, it's ugly to call `Refresh()` after, for example, 20 different events which must make the form refresh. e.g

```
private void PriorityLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _showPriorityLine = (_showPriorityLine) ? false : true;
  Refresh(); // Must call refresh for changes to take effect.
}
```

I suppose what I'm looking for is some kind of signature I can apply to the method to cause it to automatically chain to the next method, regardless from where its called. e.g

(I know this isn't syntactically correct.)

```
private void PriorityLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).Refresh()
{
   _showPriorityLine = (_showPriorityLine) ? false : true;
}
```

I want to seperate the interface of the method, from the logic contained within the method.  I understand it would be the exact amount of effort, if not more.  For example, if I were to edit the method and *accidently* removed Refresh, it would cause my application to break.  Whereas, if the Refresh method was outside of the actual logic of the method, I could do anything within the method without worrying about removing the next chain of logic.

Comment: Off-topic, consider writing the first statement as  `_showPriorityLine = !_showPriorityLine;`

Comment: Are you setting these handlers up from the designer?

Comment: @Ani Yes.  I am setting these up from the designer.

Comment: If you have to add the call in the method signature is there really a difference? You still need to deal with the multiple handlers; unless you can share the same handler...which will simplify your code.

Comment: Sounds like Aspects are what you want.

Comment: I don't do winform development, but I have a question that could lead to an answer. Are event handlers ordered? Meaning, if you have `foo.OnBar += Handler1; foo.OnBar += Handler2`, will those handlers be called in that order always? If so, you could set up a generic handler to call `Refresh`.

Comment: @Anthony No...registration order doesn't mean anything; let me rephrase...it means something but order is not guaranteed

Comment: @Aaron, OK, I suspected as much.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Yes, they are ordered. This problem is really complicated. Firstly, the OP is setting up the handlers through the desginer, which pushes the event registration code into the `designer.cs` file, which one normally doesn't mess around with. Secondly, the OP wants the continuation to be called *even* when the method is called 'vanilla', i.e. not by raising the event.

Comment: @Austin Salonen: How do you propose using aspects? It's an intriguing idea, but wouldn't it probably involve decorating every method with an attribute? If that's the solution, it doesn't improve on what the OP has already, IMO.

Comment: @Ani So as noted they are fired in the order in which they were added...however they should as noted be treated non-deterministically since they could be fired via multiple threads. I personally never concern myself with event ordering as it is generally a sign the design is flawed...excluding cleanup scenarios....

Comment: @Aaron: It's true that relying on the ordering the execution of handlers is usually not a sign of good design. I would however add that it is common to find ordering guarantees present in many WinForms apps when the controls use the same message pump.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but if you're doing graphics, consider using Invalidate() instead. Invalidate wil queue up calls to repaint various areas of a graphics surface, and paint them when Windows feels it has resources/it's time.

Comment: @Ani -- troutinator's answer was along the lines of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is Aspect Oriented Programming, there are a number of different frameworks to enable you to have stuff "magically" happen after some set of methods have run, have a look here [AOP programming in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031845/aop-programming-in-net)

Comment: +1 for being the only one to give the correct name for what the OP is describing

Comment: No reason to use a sledgehammer when a hammer -- or even a thumb -- will do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any really clean way. One method would be to use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate the changes which would cause the form to refresh into form-level properties.

For instance,

```
private bool _showPriorityLine;
private bool ShowPriorityLine
{
    get { return _showPriorityLine; }
    set
    {
        _showPriorityLine = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Then your event would just be

```
private void PriorityLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPriorityLine = !ShowPriorityLine;
}
```

Of course, that only cleans up your code if you have several events manipulating the same variables that cause the form to need refreshing.

Comment: Still pretty new to StackExchange, so this may be out of line but I'm wondering why (when I took the extra time to give the code example and explain the caveat to my solution) this was worthy of a down vote?

Did I break some protocol or something?  I was just offering an example that I use often for simple cases like this to do exactly what was requested -- cleanly separate UI from logic (without taking the time to offer up the complexity of a design pattern like MVP).

Comment: that question, no doubt, has been asked many times. Some of the voting is a mystery on this site. A lot of it has to do with people following the pack. There are cliques and cult followings here as well. Sometimes two answers say the exact same thing (posted at the same time too) and one of them will get up-voted while the other one won't. Now, to your answer specifically, look at my comment on James's answer. The same applies to you. I don't know why you got down-voted and he didn't. I suspect he's one of the "beautiful people", though.

Comment: +1 to balance out the -1 as we do have the same idea in mind. @Pedro - I don't know why my answer never got downvoted yet Eric's did, perhaps it was because mines was more of a generic/extensible solution. Or maybe people were too busy reading your back and forths with people :P IMO your solution got downvoted because you basically *demanded* that it was the correct solution and then stamped your feet because no one agreed. It's up to the OP to decide what solution best suits their requirements. All we can do is give our 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration your particular problem and the solutions posted, I would say the "cleanest" approach here would be to implement a [Property Changed Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) just for internal use in the form i.e. you don't need to expose the event like in the MSDN example.

This way you could maintain an internal list of properties that you know will require the form to be refreshed e.g.

```
  private List<string> _refreshProps = new List<string>();
  private bool _showPriority;

  public void Form()
  {
      _refreshProps.Add("ShowPriority");
      ... etc
  }

  // only implement properties like this that need some extra work done
  public bool ShowPriority
  {
      get { return _showPriority; }
      set
      {
          if (_showPriority != value)
          {
              _showPriority = value;
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged("ShowPriority");
          }
      }
  }

  // basic property that doesn't require anything extra
  public bool AnotherProperty { get; set; }

  public void Refresh()
  {
      // refresh the form
  }

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      if (_refreshProps.Contains(name))
          Refresh();
  }
```

The benefit of this approach is if in the future you needed to do other *"stuff"* after particular properties you can simply introduce another list and handle it again in your `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: One problem with this is that you may end up calling Refresh() many times because you changed many properties - when all that was required was to call Refresh() at the end.

Comment: @Pedro - Good point, although you could introduce a flag which could prevent that from happening i.e. `RefreshCount > 0`. I am just trying to give a basis from which the OP could work from.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Refresh`, call `Invalidate`. The mechanism you need is already built into Windows. Calling `Invalidate` simply makes a note that the window needs repainting. The operating system will eventually post a WM_PAINT message (typically after the root DispatchMessage call finishes, but the exact implementation is irrelevant).

Comment: While that is good advice, which I will take into account, using Refresh is just an example, and not the basis of the question. :)

Comment: You're right, I completely misread the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Use a property that calls Refresh in the setter.

Comment: this moves his "problem" to property setters rather than event handlers. He still has the same problem as before, just in a different spot.

Comment: @Anthony Technically no...if _showGridLines was set via its property ShowGridLines versus its variable instance...refresh would only be called in one place and the 2 lines would be replaced with ShowGridLines = !ShowGridLines;

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't supply the downvote. @Aaron, presumably, his 20+ events are changing different variables or properties, so those 20+ events would have 20+ properties, which would still leave `Refresh()` in 20+ different places. Unless I'm either reading or assuming something entirely wrong.

Comment: @Anthony You are correct...I was under the impression the property was the same across the multiple handlers; after looking at it again it appears the property would differ with each handler lending the above solution to not be very effective as you mentioned.

Answer (score -5):

Something like this:

```
private void RefreshAfter(Action action)
    {
        action();
        Refresh();
    }
```

UPDATED TO MAKE IT MORE OBVIOUS:

```
    private void DoSomeUiShiznit(Action action)
    {
        action();
        // other parts of the code don't realize that Refresh has to be called.
        // But that's cool. I got it covered.
        Refresh();
    }

    private void PriorityLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomeUiShiznit(() => { _showPriorityLine = !_showPriorityLine; });
    }
```

**UPDATE -- Just a message to the down-voters:**

What some of you are too blind to see is that this is not all that different from:

```
[SomeRefreshAttribute]  
private void PriorityLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    _showPriorityLine = !_showPriorityLine;  
}
```

Except that it is simpler, and doesn't require adding another framework to the solution. And yet the other answer suggesting as much don't get down-voted!

What's wrong with you people?

Comment: @George: updated to make it obvious how to use it. No charge.

Comment: @Pedro This doesn't effectively solve the issue with seperating the interface of the method from the logic. I would still need to manually call your DoSomeUiShizit method, which would only serve to add additional steps to achieve the same result.

Comment: @George: Yes, it does separate the logic. Somewhere, somehow, you will need to specify that Refresh() needs to be called. You can introduce some giant framework, or do a lot of jumping through hoops if you want. However, this method separates the intricate logic from all your other code. If you need to do more than just Refresh(), you can easily add it. Or you can remove it. And other code doesn't need to know the details. Go ahead and spend hours reading up on AOP, or use PostSharp, etc. My method is the simplest way to effectively solve your problem.

Comment: @Pedro This is *far* from the best answer. You're replacing a simple and obvious call to `Refresh()` with this obfuscated `DoSomeUiShiznit` call. It's more typing every time, for no benefit. If @George has to type out an extra function call every time anyways, he might as well type `Refresh()`. Talk about "jumping through hoops"...

Comment: @meager: Well, I applaud you on at least making a relevant comment -- even if you are mistaken. The point is to hide the fact that you need to call Refresh() every time, not the length of the method name. Change DoSomeUiShiznit() to X() if that makes you feel better.

Comment: @Pedro Read the very first sentence of the question. There is nothing **automatic** about your solution; you're replacing one word with another word. There is a 1-to-1 substitution of function calls. You're adding complexity for no gain, and **not addressing the question**.

Comment: @meagar: There is no way to *automatically* call Refresh(). As I stated earlier, *somewhere* you will have to specify that--even if some other over-the-top framework is used. If the OP wants to hide calling Refresh() -- OR, if the OP wants to do other things besides Refresh() it can easily be added (or removed) without effecting any other code.

Comment: And here is a quote from the OP: "I suppose what I'm looking for is some kind of signature I can apply to the method to cause it to automatically chain to the next method, regardless from where its called"

Comment: @Pedro Look. Your solution to "hide calling `Refresh()`" is literally equivalent to *renaming* the function from "Refresh" to "DoSomeUiShiznit()" or "X" or whatever name you choose. You've solved nothing. You're not hiding the method call in any way. I don't know why you quoted OP about applying a signature to the method, because that is not at all what you're doing.